# How to set value to telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox from javascript?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox as a input element.I want to set its value from javascript on the click event of the another button.The code for the element is as follows:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox
         runat="server"
         ID="costCodeTxt"
         Width="400"
         OnClientRequesting="requesting"
         DropDownWidth="300"
         InputType="Text"
         TextSettings-SelectionMode="Single"
         OnClientTextChanged="VerifyJobCostCode">
               <WebServiceSettings Path="~/QuantitySurvey/CostCode.asmx" Method="GetCostCodeList" />
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work to get you to the dom element, allowing you to set the value.

```
function setText(text){
    var domElement = $find("<%= costCodeTxt.ClientID %>").get_inputElement();
    domElement.value = text;
}
```

You probably also want to set this to allow custom text

```
AllowCustomEntry = "true"
```